# Warning with installing fetch to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, fetch, npm-install

When i'm installing node-fetch 
Here's [a link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)
I'm getting that warning
`-- node-fetch@1.6.3

npm WARN motivation_bot@1.0.0 No repository field.
How to resolve the problem?

Comment: It’s not a problem, so ignore it.

Comment: Does your project has name `motivation_bot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm often gives warning while installing packages. In 99%, these are mistakes made by the creator of the package, in your cause motivation_bot. You can ignore them all if your package works like it should do. You will get warnings **nearly every installation** so don't care about it ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions and install the package using the correct syntax (`npm install node-fetch --save`). After that, check your dependencies in the package.json file. If you find the package "node-fetch", you don't need to worry about the warning message.